# PrimeFaces Extensions CKEditor with MathJax Plugin

Tags: jsf, primefaces, ckeditor, primefaces-extensions

I am trying to use the Mathjax plugin for CKEditor to use mathematical formulas using Tex.

https://ckeditor.com/cke4/addon/mathjax

Doesany one knows how to solve this bug
resources-ckeditor generate this link which is wrong:
/javax.faces.resource/ckeditor/plugins/mathjax/?ln=primefaces-extensions&v=7.0.2images/loader.gif

This url works correctly 
/javax.faces.resource/ckeditor/plugins/mathjax/images/loader.gif?ln=primefaces-extensions&v=7.0.2

I am using 
primefaces 7
primefaces-extensions 7.0.2
resources-ckEditor 7.0.2

Comment: If you can create a reproducible example you should report it here: https://github.com/primefaces-extensions/primefaces-extensions.github.com/issues

Comment: OK, I will do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enhancement Ticket Opened: https://github.com/primefaces-extensions/primefaces-extensions.github.com/issues/740

Due to the nature of CKEditor and the complexity of the MathJax plugin there is no way for you to add this externally to the PFE CKeditor component.  This functionality will have to be added as a first class citizen to the PFE component.

**Update July 2020:** This plugin has been implemented for PFE 8.0.4

Comment: Can you post your solution please so others can upvote! ?

Comment: Thank you very much